# How to model the following "if, then" constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint, indicator-constraints

There are two matrices:
Matrix $S^{v\times v} \in \{0,1\}$ this is a know parameter.
Matrix $X^{v\times p} \in \mathbb{N}$. Elements of $X$ are the variables.

I want to model:
$$\textrm{if  }s_{v v'} = 1$$
$$\textrm{then  } x_{vp} + x_{v'p} \leq 1 $$

Answer (score 4):

Because $S$ is a known parameter and not a decision variable, you do not need indicator constraints or any fancy modeling.  Just check the condition on $s_{vv'}$ when you declare the constraint:
$$x_{vp} + x_{v'p} \leq 1 \quad \text{for all $v,v',p$ such that $s_{vv"}=1$}$$

Answer (score -1):

What about:
$s_{vv'}(x_{vp} + x_{v'p}) \leq 1 $

Comment: That won't work for the case $s_{vv'} = 0$. In such case, $x_{vp}$ and $x_{v'p}$ can be both equal to 1.

Comment: Ok updated the answer

Comment: @Sutanu Your updated answer is correct but a bit wasteful, introducing "empty" constraints $0 \le 1$ when $s_{vv'}=0$.  You could also replace the RHS with $s_{vv'}$, but this yields the same inefficiency.

Comment: Thanks Dr @robpratt, had put $s_{vv}$ on rhs but Daniel said $X$ needs to be free if $s=0$

Comment: I meant to keep your new LHS (with $s_{vv'}$).  Essentially, multiply both sides of $x_{vp}+x_{v'p} \le 1$ by $s_{vv'}$.  It is wasteful when it reduces to $0 \le 0$.